# Github won't allow me to push to branch

Tags: git

While attempting to push to a repo I get the following:

```
To https://github.com/Ekultek/whitewidow.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Ekultek/whitewidow.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I'm confused why it won't allow me to push?

Let's go over how I got here:

I changed around 300 lines of code, have already pulled the other repository, and have seen the whole `>>>>>HEAD` + `>>>>>>324240283<random-numbers>` thing.

However, I still can't push when I try it gives me the same output:

```
C:\Users\Justin\myscripts\rubysql\whitewidow [master +2 ~1 -0 !]> git pull https://github.com/Ekultek/whitewidow
remote: Counting objects: 169, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (30/30), done.
Receiving objects:  92% (156/169)   al 169 (delta 14), reused 3 (delta 3), pack-reused 136
Receiving objects: 100% (169/169), 56.76 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (86/86), completed with 2 local objects.
From https://github.com/Ekultek/whitewidow
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
warning: Cannot merge binary files: README.md (HEAD vs. 281bf372e265d81c0b020747e59eb7935c339d78)
Auto-merging whitewidow.rb
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in whitewidow.rb
Auto-merging log/non_exploitable.txt
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in log/non_exploitable.txt
Auto-merging log/error_log.LOG
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in log/error_log.LOG
Auto-merging log/SQL_VULN.LOG
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in log/SQL_VULN.LOG
Auto-merging lib/spider.rb
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in lib/spider.rb
Auto-merging lib/search_query.txt
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in lib/search_query.txt
Auto-merging lib/rand-agents.yaml
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in lib/rand-agents.yaml
Auto-merging lib/legal.rb
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in lib/legal.rb
Auto-merging lib/credits.rb
Auto-merging lib/copy.rb
Auto-merging docs/COPYRIGHT.md
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in docs/COPYRIGHT.md
Auto-merging docs/CHANGELOG.md
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in docs/CHANGELOG.md
Auto-merging README.md
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in README.md
Auto-merging Gemfile
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in Gemfile
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
C:\Users\Justin\myscripts\rubysql\whitewidow [master +5 ~2 -0 !9 | +5 ~1 -0 !9 !]> git push
To https://github.com/Ekultek/whitewidow.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Ekultek/whitewidow.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
```

Comment: Did you try reading the hints? What's unclear?

Comment: Well I actually read the entire `--help` section, and I pulled the repo, but it says the same thing.

Comment: ...the why don't you *mention that?!* How precisely did you get to this state?

Comment: Hehe.. Give me one second

Comment: @jonrsharpe There, it's edited, that should help

Comment: So have you tried resolving those conflicts? You certainly shouldn't push until you've got the local and remote changes into a consistent state. To put it another way, *"fix conflicts and then commit the result"*.

Comment: There are no conflicts, nothing has changed.

Comment: There are in the situation you've shown. If that's not representative of your actual problem, you're wasting your own time and everyone else's.

Comment: Well it's fixed, so thank you for the help, have a good one

Comment: Why have you accept an answer that says you need to pull? You said you already had and it didn't help! If you've solved your problem, *write an answer explaining how* so others with the same issue can learn from it. Otherwise what's the point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are some new changes in the repo, you cannot just push, you first need to pull the new changes, and after that you cant push.

on the other hand, you can do git push -f to force the push, but I think you do not want to do that.. :)

Comment: So I need to clone the repository before I can push it?

Answer (score 0):

The origin repository has been updated and you haven't updated your local repository. The typical way to update a local repository is to use the command `git push <remote> <branch>`, which if you have just created the repository and haven't created any branches or remotes, then you can just put `git push origin master` into the command line (gitbash or linux, not sure about Mac, don't think it will work on windows) in the directory that holds the `.git` file.

If you are using a GUI tool to handle git, then there is normally a button that says "pull". Click this and then try pushing again.

Comment: I just pulled the repo, and it says the same thing

Answer (score 0):

There are some commits in your remote repository that your local repository doesn't have and you have at first pull it.  I think that someone has pushed new commits to your remote repo and you have to pull it before  to push your commits.